# What happens when network connection to GCP is lost?

Tags: gcsfuse

Imagine I have a GCS bucket mounted on my local Linux file system.  Imagine I have an app that is writing new files into a Linux directory that is mounted to GCS.  My goal is to have those locally written files *eventually* show up in GCS.

I understand that the writes on Linux happen "locally" until the file is closed ... what happens if I lose network connectivity and hence can't write to GCS?  Will the local file *eventually* end up in GCS?  Do retries and re-attempts happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the repository [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse#upload-procedure-control) for `gcsfuse`, file upload retries are already built into the utility, and they happen when there are problems accessing the storage bucket that is mounted. You are able to modify the maximum backoff for retries by using the `--max-retry-sleep` flag. This flag controls the maximum time that can be reached between retries, after which retrying stops. The flag accepts an X amount of minutes as input.

[This](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse#notes) doc page is also relevant if you would like to know more about specific characteristics of `gcsfuse`.

Comment: I think I'm sensing that if I copy a file into a `gcsfuse` mounted directory and network connection to GCP isn't present, then the copy will block and, if we reach the max retry will eventually fail.  This means that writing to `gcsfuse` is a synchronous operation and not an asynchronous one?

Comment: As far as I have read from the documentation and from a test I did, apparently this behavior is as you described. The way the [upload procedure control section](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse#upload-procedure-control) describes it also seems to imply it is a synchronous operation.